# Is the combination of SQLite, MongoDB and React-Native possible?

Tags: android, mongodb, sqlite, react-native, server

We are working on a project, where we have 2 Applikations:

- one on the PC, where we have to be able to add/update data in a database, on a server
- the other on is on an android tablet, where we need to access and save this data locally to be able to use it later on offline

Our problem / question now: we are unsure, how to do this as we are all inexperienced students.

Is it possible to have Applikations in React-Native, which access a server with a database of MongoDB, then basically export the data to the Tablet and save the data to a SQLite database locally on the tablet?

We don't have to be able to save data on the PC, as this one should always be online. However, the tablet might be offline so all data should be accessible offline as well.

If you have any other suggestions, we would be glad to hear these as well. Thank you very much for you time and help.

Comment: Is it possible?  Sure.  If you're asking how to do it, that's too broad.  Come back with a more focused question.

Comment: I'm not, I was just generally asking if it was possible, or if I would be wasting my time.

Comment: It is very probably possible, because it's a common type of problem. StackOverflow is better for more specialized problems though. Just try some things out and if you encounter more specific problems on the way, ask them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible to do what you're asking. That's how most of the Android apps store data locally.

You need to write code to put the data into local database after fetching it from the server.

I think you should look more into Room.

[Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)